# RecyclerView inside of Fragment not updating

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

In my application I have a `ViewPager` that contains 5 fragments with a `RecyclerView` inside each of them. After clicking on a button I need to refresh items of my `RecyclerView`s so I'm sending request to server and get response in my activity then I'm calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` for all of my `RecyclerView`s but changes not visible until I refresh 2-3 pages of my `ViewPager`. What is wrong? here is some code from my application

Fragments:

```
public class ReservedFragment extends Fragment {
List<ReservedTimesModel> arrayList;
ReservedTimesAdapter reservedTimesAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reserved, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_recycle);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    if (arrayList != null) {
        if (!arrayList.isEmpty()) {
            reservedTimesAdapter = new ReservedTimesAdapter(arrayList, getActivity());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(reservedTimesAdapter);
        } else {
            view.findViewById(R.id.textview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        view.findViewById(R.id.textview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return view;
}

public void refresh() {
    if (reservedTimesAdapter != null) {
        if (arrayList.isEmpty()) {
            getView().findViewById(R.id.textview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            reservedTimesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Code inside of `Button` click listener in Adapter:

```
context.getReserved();
```

Code in Activity refresh after setting new list for each fragment:

```
viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
reservedFrag.refresh();
deprecatedFrag.refresh();
cancelledFrag.refresh();
cancelledByAdminFrag.refresh();
pendingFrag.refresh();
viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
```

Comment: it seems like your adapter gets notified only if the `arrayList` is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `notifyDataSetChanged` is called conditionally based on the values of variables. Maybe it is not being called at all.

Difficult to say for sure as the code is so minimal.

Comment: I was struggling with this for about 5 hours and I didn't noticed that if statement there. thanks